# Ошибка при выводе результатов парсинга твиттера

Tags: twitter, php, html, парсер, синтаксический-анализ

Вывожу у себя внизу страницы 5 сообщений из твиттреа
http://sellfile.ru/

но они почему выводятся все разом а не по отдельности, хотя использую цикл

```
                    <?php
                require_once 'simple_html_dom.php'; // библиотека для парсинга
                $username = 'Kolyambiy'; // Имя в twitter
                $maxpost = '5'; // к-во постов
                $html = file_get_html('https://twitter.com/' . $username);
                $i = '0';
                foreach ($html->find('div.ProfileTweet-contents') as $article) { //выбираем все li сообщений
                    $item['text'] = $article->find('p.ProfileTweet-text', 0)->innertext; // парсим текст сообщения в html формате
                    $item['time'] = $article->find('small.time', 0)->innertext; // парсим время в html формате
                    $articles[] = $item; // пишем в массив
                    $findme = '<a';
                    $pos = strpos($item['text'], $findme);
                    $rest = substr($item['text'], 0, $pos);
                    ?>

                    <li class="item active">
                        <span><?php echo $rest ?></span>
                    </li>
                    <?php
                    $i++;
                    if ($i == $maxpost)
                        break; // прерывание цикла
                }
                ?>
```

Библиотеку для парсинга брал тут http://habrahabr.ru/post/176635/ но она работает, подскажите что не так делаю?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все до меня дошло в чем не так. Ошибку допустил. вывожу все записи как <li class="item active"> а надо только первую, а остальные только <li class="item">